# Reliable queue based inter-thread messaging in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I’m trying to use the queue.Queue() class to communicate between threads.  I never had a problem with it in 2.x, but lately, it has seemed really unreliable to me in 3.x.

I start with a queue, as a global variable in a module.  Both threads are in this module.

```
q = queue.Queue()
```

Thread 1 has a put command:

```
global q
q.put(“Hello”)
```

Thread 2 has a get command:

```
global q
z = q.qsize()
q.get_nowait()
```

I can see in the pycdev debugger that 1 is not empty after the put, but the get is still returning empty and z is 0 before the get command.  This seems really strange to me.  I suspected mismatched scopes, but can't figure out where this might be happening.  Does anyone have an idea conditions could cause this?

Or is there a more reliable, recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Show actual reproducible code

Comment: Since you ask for a recommend way, you could create your queue and pass it to your different threads through `args`.

Answer (score 0):

Update.  I found the source of the problem and it is reproducable.  Here is runnable, sample code:

```
from bottle import route, run, response
import time
import sys
import threading
import queue

engineStartQueue = queue.Queue()

class EngineStarter(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        try:
            global engineStartQueue
            startParams = engineStartQueue.get_nowait()

            #let url handler return 
            engineStartQueue.put_nowait([200, "Starting..."])
            time.sleep(10.0)
        except Exception as e:
            fullerror = sys.exc_info()
            errorID = str(fullerror[0])
            errorMsg = str(fullerror[1])
            alertMessage = "%s, %s" %(errorID, errorMsg)
            engineStartQueue.push([500, alertMessage])


@route('/admin/start', method='POST')
def start():   
    try:
        global engineStartQueue
        engineStartQueue.put("Hello")
        starter = EngineStarter()
        starter.start()

        time.sleep(3.0)  #Give the EngineStarter instance a couple of seconds to read the queue and respond
        returnParams = engineStartQueue.get_nowait()

        response.status = returnParams[0]
        return(returnParams[1])
    except Exception as e:
        fullerror = sys.exc_info()
        errorID = str(fullerror[0])
        errorMsg = str(fullerror[1])
        returnStr = "Failed to start:  %s, %s" %(errorID, errorMsg)
        response.status = 500
        return returnStr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

It is a bottle app, with a fire and forget REST call.  There is url handler, a threadable object and a globally visible queue.

The URL handler
1 - creates an instance of the threadable object, EngineStarter
2 - Passes "Hello" to the queue
3 - Starts the thread
4 - Waits 3 seconds and gets the response from the EngineStarter thread
5 - Returns the http response code to the caller

The EngineStarter thread:
1 - Reads the queue
2 - Responds with an http ok if the thread is not empty and a 500 error otherwise
3 - The engine starter thread now waits 10 seconds, to simulate a long running background task on the server

If I start the script in the pydev debugger and then call the handler without any breakpoints set, I get an http 200 response after 3 seconds.  This means that the scope was shared.

If I set a breakpoint before looking into the queue, it is empty.  If I set the breakpoint after looking into the queue, then get_nowait() picks up "Hello".

It seems as if breakpoints in the pydev debugger are affecting the scope somehow.